# How to add values to a column attribute in such a manner that it always starts with 'A' or 'EA' or 'JW' in SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have used the following code during table creation but still faced various errors related to it

```
create table Product_Ordered
(
  Order_id     varchar(7) Not null,
  Product_id   varchar(10) Check (Product_id LIKE 'A%' or 'Ea%' or 'Jw%') Primary Key Not Null,
  Quantity     integer,
  Foreign Key  (Order_id) references Order1(Order_id) 
);
```

Comment: You can fix it yourself, with the following help: `PRODUCT_ID like <expr1> or <expr2> or ...` is incorrect; the right way to write it is `PRODUCT_ID like <expr1> or PRODUCT_ID like <expr2> or PRODUCT_ID like ...` Note though: in your question title, all the strings are capitalized, EA and JW - but in your attempt you have Ea and Jw. What is with that? Computers will do **exactly** what you tell them to do, you can't be inconsistent like that and expect good results.

Comment: Which database do you use? Is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Also - why do you need a Not Null constraint on a Primary Key?